# Problem with long polling with JQuery on Tomcat Server

Tags: jquery, tomcat, comet, long-polling

I created a CometServlet according to this example http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/aio.html. Then I tried to get data from it using JQuery. The code is following:

```
$(function() {

        $.longPoll = function(url, success, error) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            success: function(data, status) {
                $.longPoll(url, success, error);
                if (success) {
                    success(data, status);
                }
            },
            error: function(data, status) {
                $.longPoll(url, success, error);
                if (error) {
                    error(data, status);
                }
            }
        });

    };

    $.longPoll("./comet", "", function(data, status) {
        alert("success:" + data);
    }, function(data, status) {
        alert("error:" + data);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the success function doesn't trigger (even though I can see in the FireBug console that the data comes). I think it happens because the server doesn't close a response writer, but it is a goal of the long-polling :)

Does any one have any ideas how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solution is to add timer for checking the long-poll stream for a new data. Great explanation is here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1976-Long-Polling-Experiment-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the `xhr onreadystatechange` in order to check for `readyState === 3` with jQuery `.ajax()`. Example:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({});
xhr._onreadystatechange = xhr.onreadystatechange;  // save original handler

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     xhr._onreadystatechange();         // execute original handler
     if (xhr.readyState === 3) alert('Interactive');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I added:

<code>
beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                xhr._onreadystatechange = xhr.onreadystatechange;
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 3) {
                        alert(this.responseText);
                    } else {
                        xhr._onreadystatechange();
                    }
                };
                xhr.onprogress = xhr.onreadystatechange;
            }
</code>

to my $.ajax() request, but nothing changed. Sorry, I can't format the code.